# Can anyone guide that which which Schema markup is used?

Tags: schema, markup

I want to know how to use schema markup for this type of SERP result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psaZe.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

you can use ImageObject schema, you can find it here
https://schema.org/ImageObject